# Define unique key in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, unique-key

I have three models in my project.

```
 public class Bank{
   private int id;
   private String title;
   ....
}
public class Branch{
   private Bank bank;
   private int id;
   private String title;
   ....
}
public class Account{
   private Branch branch;
   private int id;
   private String accountNumber;
   private String title;
   ....
}
```

how to define the accountNumber and id Of bank combined as a unique key?

Comment: your question is not clear enough to me. Do you want to make the Bank unique within the account class....?

Comment: can you elaborate more...your question is unclear

Answer (score 1):

For composite unique key, you can use `uniqueConstraints` property of `@Table` annotation:

```
@Table(
    name = "account",
    uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"accountNumber", "bank"})}
)
public class Account{
    private Branch branch;
    private int id;
    private String accountNumber;
    private String title;
    @ManyToOne
    private Bank bank;
}
```